# Maillard Freewheel refurbishing

Tags: freewheel

I have a Maillard freewheel, big cog stamped 10 - 84, which i have taken apart, cleaned, lubed, and reassembled following the excellent youtube by RJ the bike guy

.

i don't know for certain, but i may have "misplaced" the spacers which slide down the body and allow the pin spanner locknut from crushing the bearings. the freewheel is back together, but i cannot tighten the locknut and still have the cogs rotate.

Q; how far up the river am i, and what can i do to get new spacers/ what size?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

this week should be the litmus test. i had to order a freewheel removal tool (Maillard 40 mm x 24 notch if memory serves) and i have found 2 companies* that might have the parts i need. i've had to put it down for a couple of days and take a deep breath. i'll regroup and go at it again when the remover arrives.

- Bike Tools Etc. &
  Loose Screws Bicycle Small Parts